# MongoDb pushing data to an array of objects

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using expresjs and mongoose to update a mongodb database. I'm trying to push a new object to an existing array named 'dates'. However only the 'date' field is added to the array. The other field is not seen after update. Additionally if I change the name of the field anything else other than 'date' this field will also not added.

```
router.post("/addDate", (req, res, next) => {
  // console.log(req.body.description, req.body.date, req.body.courseId)
  Course.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.courseId }, {
    $push:
    {
      dates: {
        description: req.body.description, date: req.body.date
      }
    }
  })
    .then(respData => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: respData
      })
    })
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRHFF.png)

I'm working on this problem during 3 hours.

Comment: If you pass option `{ strict: false }`, what happens?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: I doubt `req.body.date` is a `Date` object. Storing date values as string is a design flaw, you should **never** do that.

Comment: What is the value you like to add? For me, your update works.

Comment: have you added the keys which you are trying to add in the mongoose schema defination?

Comment: I found that I did not add the keys in the schema, came here to delete the post and see Smriti Shikha's suggestion. Amazingly spotted my problem so accurately. Thanks a lot.